# How to search in listbox?

Tags: delphi

I need a method that searches in listbox and highlight all the words that equal the searched word.

Can someone help me?

Comment: And WE need people to accept answers to their questions. As far as I can tell you have asked 7 questions here on StackOverflow, but you haven't accepted a single answer yet.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to perform a fast search in Listbox and get Index of similar item or exact item, the solution is like this

```
var
  i : integer;
  s : string;
begin
  s := 'My Text' +#0;
  i := Lst1.Perform(LB_FINDSTRING, $FFFFFFFF, PWideChar(s));
end;
```

`i` is index of Listbox item which is similar with your given string.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
procedure TForm1.HighLight(aListbox: TListBox; aStr: string);
var
  I : integer;
begin
  aListbox.ClearSelection;

  for I := 0 to aListbox.Items.Count-1 do
    if aListbox.Items[I] = aStr then
      aListbox.Selected[I] := true;
end;
```

You need to set the listbox's MultiSelect property to true for this to work.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I think by highlighted he means something in the style of changing the background or font color of the word, not selecting it.

Comment: I thought of that, but given the vagueness of his question and the fact that the listbox doesn't have any highlight features, I thought maybe this was what he meant. After all, many users call selected items "highlighted", or even "blue". My mother for instance :-)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what your problem exactly is. Do you need help for searching? or do you need help for highlighting words?

For searching, are you looking for a specific item in the listbox, or a word in all items?
If you want to search for an item, you can use TListBox.Items.IndexOf().
If you want to search for a word, you can either search for it in the whole text using Pos() or PosEx() functions on TListBox.Items.Text. or use those functions on every items by iterating over items, using TListBox.Items.

For highlighting words, TListBox itself does not provide text highlighting. If you need that, you have to custom draw it. Set its Style property to lbOwnerDrawFixed, and write your custom drawing code for OnDrawItem event.